# Switch component doesn't update the view

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-router

I encouter a problem with my react app, using react-router-dom v5.

When I change the route manually or when I use , the component does not update, even when I'm refreshing the page.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import openSocket from "socket.io-client"

import ChannelSelection from './auth/ChannelSelection'
import Home from './home/Home'

import AppContext from '@context/AppContext'

const App = () => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState()

  const [channel, setChannel] = useState('')
  const [pseudo, setPseudo] = useState('')

  const store = {
    user: {
      pseudo: pseudo,
      setPseudo: (pseudo) => setPseudo(pseudo)
    },
    app: {
      channel: channel,
      setChannel: (channel) => setChannel(channel)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const host = '127.0.0.1'
    const port = '8080'

    setSocket(openSocket(host + ':' + port))
  }, [])

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exactPath="/" component={() => <ChannelSelection socket={socket} />} />
          <Route path="/:channel" component={() => <Home socket={socket} />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

I'm a little bit confused rigth now because I've already use react-router-dom in the past and never encouter this problem.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is `exactPath` prop? Typo, should probably fix and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using *path* not *exactPath* I think?

```
<Route path="/" exact component={() => <ChannelSelection socket={socket} />}
```

The path will be useful if you have multiple paths with similar names. Like *path="/some"* and *path="/some/path"* which is where you'd need the exact keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `exact` props in the `routes` and change the `exactPath` to `path`.

> There is no prop with `exactPath` name in `react-router-dom`.

```
 <Route path="/" exact component={() => <ChannelSelection socket={socket} />} />
```